# How to construct Date with aggregation framework in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have simple MongoDB collection:

```
> db.installer.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51a875c83146de1db23d25d4"),
"dt" : ISODate("2013-05-31T10:04:56.567Z"),
"ev" : "screenDisplay_welcome"
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51a875c83146de1db23d25d5"),
"dt" : ISODate("2013-05-31T10:04:56.568Z"),
"ev" : "distribution"
}
...
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51a87a4d3146de1e6a8de9e2"),
"dt" : ISODate("2013-05-31T10:24:13.901Z"),
"ev" : "screenDisplay_welcome"
}
```

'ev' - some event.
'dt' - datetime of this event

I want to get statistics about this events grouped by event name and event day:

```
> db.installer.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{ev:'$ev', dt:{$dayOfYear:'$dt'}}, sum:{$sum:1}}}, {$project:{sum:1, _id:0, name:'$_id.ev', dt:'$_id.dt'}}])
{
"result" : [
    {
        "sum" : 8,
        "name" : "uninstall",
        "dt" : 151
    },
    {
        "sum" : 3,
        "name" : "screenDisplay_installServices",
        "dt" : 151
    },
    {
        "sum" : 558,
        "name" : "distribution",
        "dt" : 151
    },
    {
        "sum" : 115,
        "name" : "screenDisplay_welcome",
        "dt" : 151
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
```

Here i user **$dayOfYear** command to drop time for all events. 
Is there any way I can construct my Date object back inside aggregation pipeline?

e.g. **"dt" : 151** will be **"dt" : ISODate("2013-05-31T00:00:00.000Z")**

Comment: No, not with the aggregation framework, you cannot construct a Date object in an aggregate object expression (at least in 2.2) :-/ Would the date as a string instead of a date be an option, or possibly using MapReduce?

Comment: don't use $dayOfYear (it doesn't work right when you have more than one year's worth of data anyway) instead you can use a trick I describe here: http://www.kamsky.org/1/post/2013/03/stupid-date-tricks-with-aggregation-framework.html - basically just drop the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds from the date before the $group phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's not currently possible to construct a date in the aggregation pipeline, you could just take the first datetime instead (and process it later in your client).

For Example :

```
db.installer.aggregate([     
  {$group:      
   {          
     _id:{ev:'$ev', doy:{$dayOfYear:'$dt'} },
     sum:{$sum:1},
     date:{$first: '$dt'}
   },
  },
  {$project:{sum:1,  _id:0, name:'$_id.ev', dt:'$_id.doy', date:1}}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative to @jimoleary's solution, if you're processing it on the client anyway, why obfuscate the date to begin with? :)

```
db.installer.aggregate([
{ 
  $group: 
  { 
    _id: { ev: '$ev', doy: { $substr: ['$dt', 0, 10] } }, 
    sum: { $sum: 1 } 
  }
}, 
{
  $project:
  {
    sum: 1, _id: 0, name: '$_id.ev', dt: '$_id.doy'
  }
} 
])
```

Comment: nice! I prefer your solution.